# No module named sklearn.impute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have been trying to run this code, but nothing seems to work. this snippet of code is given on the following link in google but when I run it doesn't seems to work it shows error

> no module named sklearn.impute

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

import numpy as np

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imp_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')

imp_mean.fit([[7, 2, 3], [4, np.nan, 6], [10, 5, 9]])

SimpleImputer(copy=True, fill_value=None, missing_values=nan,strategy='mean', verbose=0)

X = [[np.nan, 2, 3], [4, np.nan, 6], [10, np.nan, 9]]

print(imp_mean.transform(X))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the package. Or uninstall and install.